# How can I get an ordered list of tables and images in word document with python?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I have to retrieve tables and previous/next images from `docx` file, but can't imagine how to obtain this with `python`.

As far as I know, we can get a list of tables with `document.tables`, but we can't get a list of images in docx with `python-docx`.

How can I get an ordered list of document elements like this

```
[
Image1,
Image2,
Table1,
Image3,
Table3,
Image4,
...
]?
```

Answer (score 0):

from the python-docx docs:

> Conceptually, Word documents have two layers, a text layer and a drawing layer. In the text layer, text objects are flowed from left to right and from top to bottom, starting a new page when the prior one is filled. In the drawing layer, drawing objects, called shapes, are placed at arbitrary positions. These are sometimes referred to as floating shapes.
>
> A picture is a shape that can appear in either the text or drawing layer. When it appears in the text layer it is called an inline shape, or more specifically, an inline picture.
>
> [...] At the time of writing, python-docx only supports inline pictures.

TLDR: you can only get the pictures if they are on the text layer. you can do so using [docx.document.inline_shapes](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.inline_shapes) which returns [InlineShape objects](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape.html#inlineshape-objects). You can check if these InlineShape objects are images with their `type` attribute.